# Get a list of files from GCS created between 2 dates using the hook

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I would like to list all the files from GCS using a prefix and the google provider hook from airflow but it doesn't work as expected.

My code python is like this:

```
midnight = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
gcs_hook = GCSHook('connection')
file_list = [os.path.basename(gcs_files) for gcs_files in gcs_hook.list_by_timespan(
                            bucket_name=BUCKET_GCS,
                            prefix=prefix_date.strftime('%Y%m%d'),
                            timespan_start=midnight, timespan_end=now,
                            delimiter='.csv')]
```

It gets all the files from the bucket with that prefix but they are not created between the 2 dates.

I read this documentation from the Airflow.
https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/stable/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/gcs/index.html#airflow.providers.google.cloud.hooks.gcs.GCSHook.list_by_timespan

Comment: It's exactly for that I wrote that article last week: https://medium.com/google-cloud/extend-cloud-storage-filtering-with-bigquery-object-table-7ce4a0f75a3d

Answer (score 0):

Posting this as a community wiki to help others that will encounter this issue:

As @guillaume blaquiere stated, there's already an article that he personally wrote for this issue. More information in this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/extend-cloud-storage-filtering-with-bigquery-object-table-7ce4a0f75a3d).